# Changing an element in a multidimensional array doesen't work in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, matrix

I made a class that represents a matrix using a multidimensional array. The initialize method goes through every position and sets the value of the elements to the one specified, and the to_s method does the same but it just concatenates every element to a string. I'm writing an insert method that changes the value of the element of a given position to a given value, but it changes a whole value instead of just an element.

```rb
class Matrix
    attr_accessor :rows, :cols, :arr

    # Goes through the matrix setting everything with the "n" value
    def initialize(r, c, n = "a")
        @rows = r
        @cols = c
        @arr = Array.new(@rows)
        tmpArray = Array.new(@cols)

        i = 0

        while i < @rows
            j = 0
            while j < @cols
                tmpArray[j] = n
                j += 1
            end

            @arr[i] = tmpArray
            i += 1
        end

        return @arr
    end

    def to_s
        i = 0
        str = String.new

        while i < @rows
            j = 0
            str  << "("

            while j < @cols
                str << " "
                if @arr[i][j].is_a?String
                    str << @arr[i][j]
                else
                    str << @arr[i][j].to_s
                end

                j += 1
            end

            str << " )\n"
            i += 1
        end

        return str
    end

    # Calls and prints to_s
    def write
        print self.to_s

        return self.to_s
    end

    # Rewrites the element (r, c) as the value in "n"
    def insert(r, c, n)
        @arr[r][c] = n

        self.write
        return self
    end
end
```

The thing is that, when I print the matrix I notice that I didn't change just an element, but a whole column of the matrix.

```rb
a = Matrix.new(2, 2, 0)
a.insert(0, 0, 1)

a.write

# Expected output: ( 1 0 )
#                  ( 0 0 )

# Real output:     ( 1 0 )
#                  ( 1 0 )
```

The to_s method isn't failing. I already made a trace of it and tested it. I'm printing the real values that are in the positions of the matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program calls `Array.new` only twice, and it doesn't create arrays using any other methods, and it doesn't use `dup` or `clone` to copy any arrays.  Therefore, you only have two different array objects in your program.  Each element of `@arr` actually points to the same row array.

One idea for a solution would be to replace this line:

```
@arr[i] = tmpArray
```

with this:

```
@arr[i] = tmpArray.dup
```

However, your code is pretty long and I have not tried running it, so I do not know if that would be a complete solution.

Comment: Your idea worked great. But I made it easier just moving the `tmpArray = Array.new(@cols)` line inside the first while loop in the initialize method so it actually creates a different array in every iteration. Thanks ^^